# Continuity of piecewise function involving rationals/irrationals and Cantor set

Tags: continuity, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, cantor-set, piecewise-continuity

I'm struggling to determine the continuity of the following function:
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}0 \quad \text{if $x \in \mathbb{Q}\cap D,$}\\ x^3 \quad \text{if $x \notin \mathbb{Q}\cap D$;} \end{cases}$$
where $D$ is the Cantor set over $[0,1]$.

I'm thinking that $f(x)$ is discontinuous for every $x\notin [0,1]\setminus (\mathbb{Q}\cap D)$ - the set of all irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ together with the set of all numbers in $[0,1]$ that are not element of $D$.

1. Can you guys send me some help? Please!
2. For these *type* of piecewise functions (which involving rationals and irrationals), is there any kind of general steps to find theirs discountinuous points?
3. I know about using $\epsilon -\delta$ definition to show that the limit at a specific point does not exist and so it is a discontinuous point, but it depends a lot on the function to choose such $\epsilon -\delta$. But I'm not sure how to use this method efficiently when I'm  trying to prove a set contains all discontinuous points of a function, any tips?.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: For piecewise functions, particularly when one piece is defined on the rationals and the other on the irrationals, there is a simple way to find the exact points of discontinuity. I wrote about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2787259/316409).

Answer (score 1):

If $x\notin\Bbb Q\cap D$, then $f(x)=x^3\ne0$. There are two possibilities now:

- $x\in D$: then, for any $\delta>0$, there s some $y\in\Bbb Q\cap D$ such that $|y-x|<\delta$. But $f(y)=0$. So, this proves, by the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition (I took $\varepsilon=x^3$) that $f$ is discontinuous at $x$.
- $x\notin D$: then, since $D$ is a closed subset of $[0,1]$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that$$(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subset[0,1]\setminus D,$$and $f(y)=y^3$ for each $y\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)$. So, $f$ is continuous at $x$.

If $x=0(\in\Bbb Q\cap D)$, then $f(x)=0$. And, for any $y\in[0,1]$, $|f(y)|\leqslant y^3$, and therefore $\bigl|f(y)-f(0)\bigr|\leqslant y^3$. So, by the squeeze theorem, $\lim>_{y\to0}f(y)=0=f(0)$, and therefore $f$ is continuous at $0$.

And if $x\in\Bbb Q\cap D$ and $x\ne0$, then $f(x)=0$. But, for each $\delta>0$, there is some $y\notin\Bbb Q\cap D$ such that $|y-x|<\delta$. Take $y$ such that $y>\frac x2$, and therefore $f(y)>\frac{x^3}8$. So, if you take $\varepsilon=\frac{x^3}8$, this proves that, for every $\delta>0$, there is some $y$ such that $|y-x|<\delta$ and that $\bigl|f(y)-f(x)\bigr|\geqslant\varepsilon$. So, $f$ is discontinuous at $x$.